# Xcode "Manage Version and Build Number" option

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I have just updated to Xcode 13 Beta and I am about to upload my first build to App Store using this version of Xcode. This version of Xcode shows a new App Store Connect distribution option which I previously haven't seen:

> Manage Version and Build Number
>
> This will change the version and build number of all content in your app to 1.2 (3).

[image]

I have already increased my version and build number from Xcode before archiving. What should we do here? If it is an automated way of build increment, what are the benefits of using it?

Comment: Unbelievably Apple of Apple to do this... We already have our own build sequence thanks. Can you maybe not turn on a new feature by default? You know, for those of us who have been happily incrementing our build numbers without your help for years now? :)

Comment: Maybe from here onwards, Apple is going towards 'automating' releases internally without a need of 3rd party tools in future.. Bec. this is what CI-CD tools do for us nowadays.

Comment: File a bug report on this behavior. It's unprofessional and dumb: feedbackassistant.apple.com

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> I have already increased my version and build number from Xcode before archiving. What should we do here?

If you are sure that you have already updated your version/build number before archiving, then you can uncheck this and this will be ignored.

> If it is an automated way of build increment, what are the benefits of using it?

1. It provides you a chance to change `version`/`build` just in case you forgot about it. There was no indication for this in previous Xcode versions.
2. It allows you to change `version`/`build` number before export/upload (**after archiving**), previously you had to create a new archive if you wanted to change the `version`/`build` number.

Comment: This actually sounds like a nice feature, just would have chosen to default to off for existing projects.

Comment: Side note: if xcodebuild 13 is overriding a CFBundleVersion value that you're already managing, set the new `manageAppVersionAndBuildNumber` property to false in your exportOptions.plist

Comment: Organizer still shows the old version number even after it's uploaded.

Comment: @JaysenMarais Can you please share any command or how we can set the `manageAppVersionAndBuildNumber` in exportOptions.plist?

Comment: @SritharRajendran Here's a [reasonable primer on exportOptions.plist](https://www.matrixprojects.net/p/xcodebuild-export-options-plist/). Once you have such a file and are passing it to `xcodebuild`, you just add a `manageAppVersionAndBuildNumber` key with a value of `false`

Answer (score 26):

For folks using fastlane and struggling with Xcode changing build version.

New in [Xcode 13](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-13-release-notes):

> When uploading an app to App Store Connect, the distribution assistant
> in Xcode detects whether your app has a valid build number
> (CFBundleVersion). If your app has an invalid number (like one that
> was used previously, or precedes your current build number), the
> distribution assistant provides an option to automatically increment
> it to a valid number. In addition, the distribution assistant ensures
> that the build numbers of all embedded content in your app (such as
> app extensions, App Clips, or watchOS apps) are in sync with your app.
> Note that this doesn’t modify your source code or your archive; Xcode
> updates the build number in a staged copy of your app before packaging
> and uploading it to App Store Connect. (59826409)

When using fastlane for building and releasing apps, you can pass "**manageAppVersionAndBuildNumber: false**" parameter to export_options of build_app action to disable xcode version change.

```
build_app( scheme: "your_app_scheme", export_options:{ manageAppVersionAndBuildNumber: false })
```

Comment: Seriously, Apple should fund fastlane. Thx.

Answer (score 15):

i ran into something unexpected with this - it also changes version numbers of frameworks embedded into the app.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690647

Comment: As a framework programmer, you can work around this by using the build-time value of `MARKETING_VERSION`. See sample code here: https://ootips.org/yonat/getting-your-framework-version-in-run-time/