# Prevent fast lane from checking App Store latest build number and increasing it

Tags: xcode, bash, continuous-integration, app-store-connect, fastlane

When I set a build number in my Xcode project lower than the latest uploaded build. Fastlane changes build number for the produced build and set it to latest+1.
Even that I disabled managing build number from Xcode and didn't set any configuration for it in my lane.

```
platform :ios do
  desc "Push a new release build to the App Store"
  lane :release do |options|
    ENV["GYM_BUILDLOG_PATH"] = options[:xcode_build_path]
#increment_build_number(build_number: options[:build_number], xcodeproj: "xxxxxx")
    build_app(scheme: "xxxxxx", xcargs: "-allowProvisioningUpdates", archive_path: options[:archive_path], output_directory: options[:output_directory], suppress_xcode_output: true)
    upload_to_app_store(skip_metadata: true, skip_screenshots: true)
  end
end
```

If apple gonna reject that build becuase the build number is lower than latest build. I want fastlane to not fix it. want the fastlane command to fail.

Comment: I hope this will help to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69837119/10659482

Comment: I ended up adding my own logic. I moved on. If I have time I will try that solution. I read it ty.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure your `build_app` script with the following `manageAppVersionAndBuildNumber` property:

```
build_app(scheme: "your_app_scheme", 
          export_options:{ 
            manageAppVersionAndBuildNumber: false 
          })
```